# Using @Html.Serialize() in Area (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement a multi-step wizard in an area of my MVC-Project. To preserve the data across the steps I use `Html.Serialize()` from the ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly.

In the whole Project `Html.Serialize()` works fine, but not in the area, here I get the error:

> System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Universal.Web.Areas.Interactive.Models.WizardData> does not contain a definition for "Serialize".

Has anyone an idea how to get it work?

I have found the answer, i have forgotten to reference the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll in the web.config of the Area.

Comment: is the area in a different assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the required namespace (Microsoft.Web.Mvc?) in the Web.Config file inside your area's views directory.